# I want to do a conditionning filter in some row to extract values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-extraction

I have a DataFrame with the first columns :

```
Brand           Price
Samsung         75.5,99.2
Lenovo          50.3
Lg              60.5,88.4
```

I want to extract the max value if the cell contains 2 values.
I try the conditioning that follows:

```
for x in df['Price']:
 if 0 <= len(x) <= 5:
  df['Price'] = df['Price'].str[0:5]
 else:
  df['Price'] = df['Price'].str[6:12]
```

but it don't work for the cells that contains a single value it returns a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

We can [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the column on the comma, then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to find the max value per row (each string needs converted to a float so that `max` will behave as expected):

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.split(',').apply(lambda c: max(map(float, c)))
```

Alternatively expand into a DataFrame and convert the entire DataFrame to float with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and get the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) per row (`axis=1`):

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float).max(axis=1)
```

Assuming the comma separated values are sorted (the last value will always be the largest), we can also just use the [`str` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) to get the last value (index `-1`):

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.split(',').str[-1]
```

All options produces output `df` (for the provide sample):

```
     Brand  Price
0  Samsung   99.2
1   Lenovo   50.3
2       Lg   88.4
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Brand': ['Samsung', 'Lenovo', 'Lg'],
    'Price': ['75.5,99.2', '50.3', '60.5,88.4']
})
```

Comment: the last option did it the way i wanted to! Very useful